# Parent / Child styling css

Tags: css

Please help me with this CSS code:

```css
#mediaswap DIV { position: absolute; display: none; }
#mediaswap { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
#mediaswap div:nth-child(1) { display:block; }​
```

I hide all my `div`s under mediaswap with `display: none`, and then display only the first child `div` with `display: block`.

How can I get all of the contents within that first child to `display: block`?

Comment: That will work with the correct `mediaswap` contents HTML layout, but it'll never work if the HTML is like this: `<div id="mediaswap"><div><span>text</span><div>childDIV</div></div></div>`. i.e.: the "text" span will never be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```css
#mediaswap div:nth-child(1) * { display: block; }​
```

Comment: This isn't working.  Maybe I am doing the wrong thing.. I have display none for everything, but the last div I want it to be normal.. Block seems to be breaking stuff because of my floats?  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not actually hiding any of the children, it shouldn't be an issue. Nth child is good if you're targeting a specific one, but you can use first child. And you need to target the parent's first child. Something like:

```
#mediaswap { overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#mediaswap div { display: none; position: absolute; }
#mediaswap:first-child { display:block; }​
```

Comment: Plus, [`:first-child`](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-child) (CSS2) has better browser-compatibility than [`:nth-child`](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) (CSS3).